# script to find multi second difference between two lines in SystemOut.log

Tags: websphere

Here is the problem - 
I have a gap in my SystemOut.log of 26 seconds (typically this gap would be no more than a second at most).
I believe there is a downstream issue going on but I need to find more instances of this occurrence to ask SAP person to investigate. Yes, scanning SystemOut.log for a >15 second gap between entries - I have very little hair left.
So I was hoping to script a readline that would differentiate one line from the next and calculate if TimeStamp is more then 10 seconds off from previous.
I am just not sure how I should approach this.
Any suggestions?

I think in simplest terms what I am trying to do is:

readline = line1
read nextline = line2
    if line2 is gt 10 seconds than line1
        printline
    else
        Continue
line1 = line2
line2 = nextline

I found BASH answers that come real close and I am still hunting.  But I am uncertain how to move to nextline and re-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need, I have re-used the guts many times to count deltas for different matching lines in WebSphere logs:

https://github.com/covener/plugin-tools/blob/master/wasgaps.pl